# How to clear Drupal.settings?

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

The problem is that I am using ajaxed form with clientside validation which uses Drupal.settings to get some data. As an example to validate age I set following data to drupal settings:

```
drupal_add_js(array(
'viewpoint_profile' => array(
  'year' => date('Y'),
  'month' => date('m'),
  'day' => date('d')
)), 'setting');
```

But whenever form is reloaded with ajax it merges above settings to Drupal.settings and if on first call `Drupal.settings.viewpoint_profile.year == 2011`, after ajax reload it is `Drupal.settings.viewpoint_profile.year == array(2011, 2011)`, so I can't use this in js as a string any more.

So basically it would be nice to clear settings for viewpoint_profile before adding them, but I didn't manage to find how? or may be there is another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Detached setting assignment from form and moved it to module's hook_init. May be not the best solution, but now it works as it should.

Comment: Did you find a better solution +1 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you must use the drupal settings than why not as those values to an array.

```
drupal_add_js(array(
  'viewpoint_profile' => array(array(
    'year' => date('Y'),
    'month' => date('m'),
    'day' => date('d')
))), 'setting');
```

You can also add a key that will be passed with the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
// Create clon of 'viewpoint_profile'.
let viewpointProfile = $.extend(true, {}, settings.viewpoint_profile);
delete settings.viewpoint_profile;
// Use viewpointProfile instead of settings.viewpoint_profile.
```